# Dijit DateTextBox set date in a year lower thatn 100

Tags: date, dojo, dijit.form

I am trying to set an really old value in a DateTextBox. Unfortunately the widget won't accept dates set in a year lower than '100'.

When I try to set the value of the element to `0017-01-01` the widget automatically sets itself to `2017-01-01`.

The displayed value property keeps unchanged until the widget gets out of focus, then it is changed to the internal date.

```
<input type="date" 
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" 
    value='0017-01-01' 
    id="myDate" />
```

Is there any way to allow older dates `0100-01-01` in the `DateTextBox`?

I also build a small jsfiddle to demonstrate the effect: 
 http://fiddle.jshell.net/shfe1oqs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `constraint strict == true` to your `DateTextBox`:

```
<input type="date" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" 
 data-dojo-props="constraints: {strict: true}" value='0017-01-01' id="myDate" />
```

The modified jsfiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/fuzxt1fb/3/

Note that then you will have to enter two digits values for day and month

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the internal date of the widget is still set to Sun Jan 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET). According to the [api documentation](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojo/date/locale#1_10dojo_date_locale_parse) the date parser used in dojo just doesn't allow dates older than the year 100 :(

Comment: Are you sure ? Don't you get on the modified jsfiddle:  "Internal value of widget: Thu Jan 12 0017 00:00:00 GMT+0100", which is what I get ? The API doc that you mention says: "year < 100CE requires strict mode". I could confirm in the debugger that the dojo.locale parse function does return a date object with value  Date 0017-01-16T23:00:00.000Z (my local zone is Paris), which gets stored in the 'value' widget property.

Comment: I am sorry, the solution did not work in the jsfiddle for me (tried in different browser etc) I made da minimal local test and it worked. Thanks a lot :)